# junit manipulation filter not found in eclipse

Tags: junit, noclassdeffounderror

I have setup my test in /src/test/bdd/integration/java folder, when I try to run my test I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/manipulation/Filter
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadTestLoaderClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:208)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your project is not maven based.

Run -> Run Configurations

Open the tab "Classpath", click the button "Advanced..." on the left

Select "Add Library" --> Junit

Then, under the 'User Entries', you will see the Junit library.